# Json custom deserializer not called in Websphere

Tags: rest, jackson, jax-rs, websphere

I have simple class and field `id` is annotated with custom deserializer.

```
public class TestRequest implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9=+]*$")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;

//getter
//setter
}
```

and the custom deserializer class :

```
public class StringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {


    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) {

Iterator<String> iterator = jsonParser.readValuesAs(String.class);
String id = iterator.next();
return id + "0000";     
    }
}
```

When i test with with Jersey REST test, the deserilizer is called and works as expected. But with websphere it does not called. Any idea why its not called.
I am using jaxrs 1.1

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the `@Provider` annotation to your `StringDeserializer` class, otherwise the JAX-RS runtime will not recognize the class as a provdier.

Even though your class extends `JsonDeserializer<String>`, which itself is probably annotated with `@Provider`, the JAX-RS runtime will not scan libraries for annotations, as doing negatively impacts performance.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working in Websphere by moving the annotation   @JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class) to setter method of the class

```
public class TestRequest implements Serializable {

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9=+]*$")
@JsonProperty
private String id;

@JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class)
public setId(String id){ 
this.id=id;  
}

//getter
//setter
}
```